# Python Loop Help - Calculating PI using Gregory–Leibniz series

Tags: python, math

I am having an issue getting the python 2.5 shell to do what I need to do. I am trying to have the user input a value for "n" representing a number of times the loop will be repeated. In reality, I need to have the user input N that  will correspond to the number of terms from the Gregory–Leibniz series and outputs the approximation of pi.

Gregory–Leibniz series
pi=4*((1/1)-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)-(1/11)+(1/13)...)

So when n is 3,I need the loop calculates up to 1/5. Unfortunately, it is always giving me a value of 0 for the variable of total.

My code as of right now is wrong, and I know that. Just looking for some help. Code below:

```
def main():
    n = int(raw_input("What value of N would you like to calculate?"))
    for i in range(1,n,7):
        total = (((1)/(i+i+1))-((1)/(i+i+2))+((1)/(i+i+4)))

    value = 4*(1-total)
    print(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's not Fermat's Last Theorem. FLT is about adding numbers together raised to the same power. Not about pi.

Comment: Sorry about that. That is my mistake. For some reason I thought it was Fermat.

Comment: It could be that your problem is that integers use integer division, so `1/2==0`. If you use `1.0` in place of `1` you will get float division instead.

Comment: Look at the print function. O/P is using Python 3.0. Don't need explicit floating point.

Comment: @GaryWalker "...an issue getting the python 2.5 shell to do what I need ..."

Comment: @GaryWalker That version of print is required in Python 3, but also works in Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses integer division, so you will get zero:

```
total = (((1)/(i+i+1))-((1)/(i+i+2))+((1)/(i+i+4)))
```

Instead, use floats to get float division.

```
total = ((1.0/(i+i+1))-(1.0/(i+i+2))+(1.0/(i+i+4)))
```

In python 2, by default doing `/` on integers will give you an integer.

In python 3, this has been changed, and `/` always performed float division (`//` does integer division).

Comment: You can also call `from future import division` (or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

You need to accumulate terms. e.g.

```
total = 0.0
term = 1.0
for i in range (1,n+1):
    denom = 2*i-1
    total += term/denom
    term = -term
```

Of course, you can express this more tersely

It is also more natural perhaps to  use this instead

total = 0.0
term = 1.0
for i in range (n):
    denom = 2*i+1
    total += term/denom
    term = -term

As you use the most natural form of of n terms in a range this way. Note the difference in how denominator is calculated.

Comment: `total += 1/denom`  will convert return `int` not `float`

Comment: O/P is using Python 3 -- look at the print statement

Comment: @GaryWalker You can use `print(value)` in 2.5, and the question **explicitly** says that he's using 2.5. Your answer will not help the OP because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 to find the Leibniz formula for π. Let S be the sequence of terms that is used to approximate π. As we can see, the first term in S is +1, the second term in S is -1/3 and the third term in S is +1/5 and so on. Find the smallest number of terms such that the difference between 4*S and π is less than 0.01. That is, abs(4*S – math.pi) <= 0.01.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you wrap your code in backticks `\`like this\`` your posts will be much more beautiful.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  You're saying how to use the Leibniz formula to calculate π to some accuracy.  The question is how to get a non-zero value of the formula when you already know you want n terms.